# How to find unrated models with acts_as_rateable

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application using the `acts_as_rateable` plugin.

I'm stuck on figuring out how to retrieve unrated models using this plugin - however this is more of a general rails/SQL question than specific to this plugin.

Acts as rateable adds the following to the schema:

```
create_table "ratings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "rating",                      :default => 0
    t.string   "rateable_type", :limit => 15, :default => "", :null => false
    t.integer  "rateable_id",                 :default => 0,  :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id",                     :default => 0,  :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "ratings", ["user_id"], :name => "fk_ratings_user"
```

And my rated models also have a user id column.

I'd like to be able to retrieve all instances of a particular model that haven't been rated at all, and also all instances that haven't been rated by someone other than the creator of the model, e.g. here is one model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_rateable

  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

So I want something like the following pseudocode

```
Review.find(:all, :conditions=>"not rated by anyone")
Review.find(:all, :conditions=>"not rated by anyone except review.user")
```

However I can't figure out the SQL to do this, nor the rails magic to generate that SQL :-)

Update: this query seems to find all models that ARE rated by somebody other than the user that owns the model. So I think I just need to invert this somehow.

```
 Review.find(:all, 
  :joins=>'left join ratings on reviews.id=ratings.rateable_id && ratings.rateable_type="Review"', 
  :conditions=>'reviews.user_id <> ratings.user_id', 
  :group=>'reviews.id')
```

Comment: Do unrated models have a rating of zero?

Comment: Yes they do, at least they do when using the rails interface - i.e. Review.find(1).rating == 0 if there are no ratings for that model

Answer (score 1):

Named scopes are the way to go for this problem. I would add two named scopes to your `Review` model. Something like:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_rateable

  belongs_to :user

  named_scope :not_rated, :conditions => { :rating => 0 }
  named_scope :not_rated_by_others,
              :conditions => ["user != ? AND rating == 0", self.user]
end
```

Then you can do:

```
@not_rated = Review.not_rated
@not_rated_by_others = Review.not_rated_by_others
```

There's a [Railscast that explains named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope).

---

**EDIT: Second Attempt**

Right, let's have another go! One of the problems is that there are multiple `acts_as_rateable` plugins out there. I've been testing using [this one](http://rateableplugin.rubyforge.org/) on RubyForge.

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  acts_as_rateable

  named_scope :not_rated, :select => 'reviews.*',
              :joins => 'left join ratings on reviews.id = ratings.rateable_id',
              :conditions => 'ratings.rateable_id is null'

  named_scope :not_rated_by_others, lambda { |user| { :select => 'reviews.*',
              :joins => 'left join ratings on reviews.id = ratings.rateable_id',
              :conditions => ['ratings.user_id != ? and ratings.rateable_id is null',
                 user] }}
end
```

Use it like this:

```
frank = User.find_by_name('frank')
@not_rated = Review.not_rated
@not_rated_by_others = Review.not_rated_by_others(frank)
```

Comment: I like the named_scope idea, but unfortunately the query itself doesn't work as there is no 'rating' column, it is something calculated by the rating plugin.  So, in the console Review.find(1).rating works but not in SQL. Similarly Review.find(1).ratings == [] in the console.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have chance to test it. I'll see if I can take a look tonight.

Comment: you need to include the rateable_type = @@whatever_model_type in your join statement, cause the ratings table is polymorphic so if you have ratings on other things it will return other classes in your result set

Comment: I haven't tried but I don't understand how this would work. Let's say I have Review id = 2 and it has no ratings. In that case, there should be no rows in the ratings table with rateable_type=='Review' && rateable_id==2. So I don't think testing for rateable_id is null is correct - because there shouldn't be any rows with null in that column (this is actually enforced by the schema, besides). The lack of rating is reflected in the absence of the row, as I understand it.

Comment: This must be a difference in the plugins we are using - when I run Review.not_rated I get an empty result ([]), even tho there is at least one Review with no ratings. I believe this is because as I describe above unrated models do not have any rows in the rating table, i.e. when Review.find(1).ratings==[] is true, then Rating.find(:all,:conditions=>'rateable_id=1 && rateable_type="Review"') == [] is also true. So I need to come up with a query that finds all models (of a given type) *except* those that appear in the rating table, plus add a condition to firstly remove ratings by a given user.

Comment: Correction, the problem is actually harder than that because the user varies by model. I don't just want to ignore all ratings by user 'foo', I want to treat as unrated any models where the user doing the rating is the same as the user that created the model.

Answer (score 0):

I've got some of the way using a query like this:

```
Review.find(:all, 
 :joins=>'left outer join ratings on reviews.id=ratings.rateable_id && ratings.rateable_type="Review"',
  :conditions=>'ratings.rating is NULL')
```

This looks like it returns all Review models with no rating at all.

And I think this one is working to find all Review models that aren't rated by the user who created the review:

```
Review.find(:all, 
  :joins=>'left outer join ratings on reviews.id=ratings.rateable_id && ratings.rateable_type="Review" && ratings.user_id <> reviews.user_id',
  :conditions=>'ratings.rating is NULL')
```